# Unix/Linux pipe behavior when reading process terminates before writing process

Tags: c, linux, pipe

I have this:

```
$ ls -lh file
-rw-r--r-- 1 ankur root 181M Sep 23 20:09 file

$ head -6 file

z
abc
abc
abc
abc
abc

$ cat file | grep -m 1 z
z
```

Question:

Why is the `cat` command line in the last line not dying prematurely with SIGPIPE? I think this should happen because `grep` terminates in no time compared to `cat file` that cats 183MB of file. With reading process gone `cat` will try to write to a broken pipe and should die with SIGPIPE.

Update:

I ended up writing this: readstdin.c

```
# include <unistd.h>
# include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    ssize_t n ;        
    char a[5];        
    n = read(0, a, 3);
    printf("read %zd bytes\n", n);
    return(0);

}
```

I use it like this:

```
$ cat file | ./readstdin
$ yes | ./readstdin
```

But still `cat` or `yes` does not die prematurely. I expect it to because by reading process is terminating before writing process is done writing.

Comment: `yes` is dying, otherwise it would stay for ever...

Comment: As Basile Starynkevitch said, the `cat` and `yes` processes receive a `SIGPIPE` signal and get killed.  The exit status of a pipeline is the exit status of the final command (i.e. `grep`), so if an earlier command fails, you won't see that in the exit status.  What makes you think they're not dying prematurely?

Comment: @AdamRosenfield What makes you think they're not dying prematurely is the fact that I am not seeing an error message printed on the screen from `cat` or `yes` , they just silently exit. But that could be how they are implemented to handle SIGPIPE.

Comment: @abc: The default behavior of a `SIGPIPE` signal is to silently terminate the process.  Try compiling and running a program that only does `main() { raise(SIGPIPE); }` -- it produces no output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the read end of some [pipe(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html) is [close(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/close.2.html)-ed, further [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html)s will get a `SIGPIPE` [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html). Read also [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html).

<sup>They would get the `SIGPIPE` when the pipe buffer becomes full.</sup>

In the `yes | ./readstdin` command, the `yes` command gets a a `SIGPIPE` signal. Just try `yes` in a terminal, it spits some output *indefinitely ad nauseam* till you kill it.

In the `cat file | ./readstdin` command, it could happen (notably if `file` is quite small, less that `sysconf(_POSIX_PIPE_BUF)` bytes, which might be 4096 bytes), that the `cat` command is `close(2)`-ing the `STDOUT_FILENO` descriptor and that the pipe is still not full. Then `cat` may not get any `SIGPIPE`.

Comment: Please see my update to the question.Any insights will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Normal processes close the input stream causing a SIGPIPE. In the man page, it mentions that `-m` stops reading, and "ensures that standard input is positioned to just after the last matching line before exiting". So it doesn't actually close the stream. You can demonstrate like this:

```
cat file | (grep -m1 z && grep -m1 c)
```

You'll get the first `c` after the first `z`, which is sometimes useful.  After the last grep exits, there is no place for the stream to go, so it's left unread and the whole group of commands exits. You can demonstrate:

```
(while true; do echo z; sleep 1; done) | grep -m3 z
(while true; do echo z; sleep 1; done) | grep --line-buffered z | head -3
```

Comment: What if the reading process dies (or is done) before the writing process completed ? What would happen in that case?